# Can I make a Blazor application that doesn't open in a browser tab?

Tags: c#, iis, blazor, devexpress

When I make a Blazor app, it always opens in a new browser tab with a list of pages on the left side of the screen and a title header across the top. However, I'd like it to just open a DxWindow (I'm using DevExpress) like when you make a windows form. Is this possible if I'm using Blazor with DevExpress? For reference, I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and C#.

I made a DxWindow that opens automatically when the default browser tab opens. I also removed all the pages from the browser tab's UI in an effort to get to a blank tab, since I can't figure out how to stop it from opening entirely. The header's still there, though.

I also tried making a windows form using Blazor, but I ultimately need to run this app through IIS, and windows forms can't be displayed via IIS.

Also, I don't want to use JavaScript at all. Just C#, HTML, and CSS in Blazor.

Comment: What type of Blazor application is this? Blazor Server, Blazor WebAssembly, or Maui Blazor?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, especially from the line "windows forms can't be displayed via IIS". Your application is hosted in IIS - you need a browser to view it. Can you add a screenshot of the behavior you're seeing along with a [mre]? I don't understand what you're trying to change.

Comment: This sounds like you'd like to use [Blazor Hybrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) with either MAUI, WPF or WinForms as the desktop app-part; it is [supported by DevExpress](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/400725/blazor-components)

Comment: I have no idea what kind of Blazor application I'm working with. I just made a Blazor app in VS 2022. I've never worked with Blazor before this.

Comment: Apps displayed via IIS don't need to be opened in a browser. I will not add a screenshot or an example; it's very straightforward, gunr2171.

Comment: @PatrickHenryPrior *Apps displayed via IIS don't need to be opened in a browser. I will not add a screenshot or an example; it's very straightforward* lol well this seems directly contradicted by the fact that you are asking how to do it. I'm curious what you are trying to do too but I'm not sure what idea you have in mind either. Generally if you are serving via IIS you are talking about a web app. It is possibly that (for example) a blazor assembly app could be downloaded via IIS but ran "offline" as if it were an app. Is that what you mean? Something else?

Comment: @topsail I have other apps running through IIS that don't need to open a browser tab to run. I didn't write those. I've been assigned to make a Blazor app that runs in that same IIS setup, so that's why I have to figure out how to do this in Blazor.

Comment: @topsail To clarify, I just need to make a Blazor app that opens in a DxWindow without opening a browser tab. However, Blazor projects created in Visual Studio always open via a browser tab, for some reason.

Comment: I see. Well, that is useful for context. I fear that it doesn't help enough. In essence, you are saying "how to make blazor be like my other apps" ... but we don't really know what the other apps are or how the are served from IIS in browser-less forms. Some good guesses could be made (by others with more knowledge than me). But its a little vague.

Comment: Okay, that's fair. I just mean that opening those other programs in IIS just makes a window appear, whereas when I open my Blazor app through IIS, it opens a browser with a new tab that has Blazor's proprietary purple UI stuff all over it. I have it set up now so that the tab automatically opens a DxWindow with all the content I want when the tab is opened, but I want to bypass the tab altogether.

Comment: I know that nobody really uses Blazor, so maybe it's a long shot to get an answer to a question like this, but I figured I'd at least try.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, if you have a perfectly good way of serving apps from IIS the way you want them, why go to Blazor here? For what it's worth, it does sound more like you want a MAUI app with blazor components. Can't really say how IIS would fit in though.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too, but my boss wants it done in Blazor lol. Maui might be the way to go. @Mimak mentioned Maui and WPF. I'm trying WPF right now to see if that works.

Comment: "I know that nobody really uses Blazor..." Where did you get that idea? Lots of people use Blazor. The confusing part is when you ask about what is primarily a web app framework, but you don't want a web app.

Comment: Can you explain *how* you are "opening those other programs in IIS" - IIS is a web server - it serves web applications. What steps do you follow when you are "opening those other programs in IIS"?

Comment: [Polite] And comments such as "I know that nobody really uses Blazor" doesn't set you off on the right foot or endear you to the people who are likely to answer your question.  If that's the case why are you trying?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you are trying to build a progressive web app (PWA for short).
PWAs are built with c# and blazor, are served through iis and are installable like regular apps on PC and mobile devices. They appear as regular application with their UI. Dev express components for blazor are supported.

Have a look at Microsoft documentation and check if this can suite you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

[Edit]:
Another way to achieve similar result (starting from .net 6) is to embed a BlazorWebView control in a WPF or Windows Forms application using .NET MAUI and Blazor.
Checkout this article:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-3/#blazorwebview-controls-for-wpf-windows-forms

Hope this helps.